# PHP MySQL Delete function in while loop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Evening,

I'm kinda stuck here. I've made a login for our employees to easily create new invoice (it's in danish though, sorry) and almost everything is completed. But one thing I can't figure out how to do, is to delete a material (materiale in danish) from a while loop. I've got a form with a while loop within it, which displays all of the materials, and right next to the material input fields I've created a small a href link, which should delete the field with some help from javascript. It deletes the field perfectly, but doesn't delete the data from our mysql database. So every time I refresh the page, then the data are back. Updating and inserting isn't a problem. The code looks like this:

```
$ct_update = 0;

foreach ($_POST['beskrivelse_update'] as $k => $value) {
    $beskrivelse_update = addslashes($value);
    $enhed_update           = addslashes($_POST['enhed_update'][$ct_update]);
    $stk_update         = addslashes($_POST['stk_update'][$ct_update]);
    $vejl_eks_moms_update   = addslashes($_POST['vejl_eks_moms_update'][$ct_update]);

    $update_id              = (int)$_POST['update_id'][$ct_update];

    $db->query("UPDATE faktura_materialer SET beskrivelse = '$beskrivelse_update', enhed = '$enhed_update', stk = '$stk_update', vejl_eks_moms = '$vejl_eks_moms_update', subtotal = '$stk_update' * '$vejl_eks_moms_update' WHERE id = '$update_id' LIMIT 1");

    $ct_update++;
}

$ct_ny = 0;

if(isset($_POST['beskrivelse_ny'])){
    foreach ($_POST['beskrivelse_ny'] as $k => $value) {
        $beskrivelse_ny = addslashes($value);
        $enhed_ny           = addslashes($_POST['enhed_ny'][$ct_ny]);
        $stk_ny         = addslashes($_POST['stk_ny'][$ct_ny]);
        $vejl_eks_moms_ny   = addslashes($_POST['vejl_eks_moms_ny'][$ct_ny]);

        $db->query("INSERT INTO faktura_materialer (faktura_id, beskrivelse, enhed, stk, vejl_eks_moms, subtotal) VALUES ('".$_faktura->faktura_id."', '".$beskrivelse_ny."', '".$enhed_ny."', '".$stk_ny."', '".$vejl_eks_moms_ny."', '".$stk_ny."' * '".$vejl_eks_moms_ny."')");

        $ct_ny++;
    }
}
```

Hopefully you understand what I want to do, otherwise just comment. Have a nice evening peeps :)

Edit:

I want the delete query to be submitted when the user clicks the submit button "Save changes". This is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var table = document.getElementById("produkter_rows");
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
cell1.innerHTML = '<td><input style="width:450px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="beskrivelse_ny[]" value=""></td>';
cell2.innerHTML = '<td><input style="width:60px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="enhed_ny[]" value=""></td>';
cell3.innerHTML = '<td><input style="width:30px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="stk_ny[]" value=""></td>';
cell4.innerHTML = '<td><input style="width:205px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="vejl_eks_moms_ny[]" value=""></td>';
cell5.innerHTML = '<td><a href="#" onclick="removeRow(this)" id="addNew" title="Slet produkt"><img src="images/icons/slet.gif" width="16" alt="Slet" /></a></td>';
}

removeRow = function(el) {
    $(el).parents("tr").remove()       
}
</script>
```

When the user clicks the delete icon right next to the material, then it will be deleted. And it does delete the input fields, but not from the database in mysql.

Second edit:

This is HTML and PHP for updating current data in MySQL database:

```
$materialer_query = $db->query("SELECT faktura_materialer.id as materialer_id, faktura.*, faktura_materialer.* FROM faktura, faktura_materialer WHERE faktura_materialer.faktura_id = faktura.id");

while($mat = $materialer_query->fetch_object()){
    ?>

    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="update_id[]" value="<? print $mat->id; ?>" />
        <td><input style="width:450px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="beskrivelse_update[]" value="<? print $mat->beskrivelse; ?>"></td>
        <td><input style="width:60px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="enhed_update[]" value="<? print $mat->enhed; ?>"></td>
        <td><input style="width:30px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="stk_update[]" value="<? print $mat->stk; ?>"></td>
        <td><input style="width:205px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="vejl_eks_moms_update[]" value="<? print $mat->vejl_eks_moms; ?>"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><a href="#" onclick="removeRow(this)" id="addNew" title="Slet produkt"><img src="images/icons/slet.gif" width="16" alt="Slet" /></a></td>
    </tr>

    <?
}
```

The hidden input field `name="update_id[]"` is added to the form when I am updating. I hope this helps...

Comment: Can't find your `DELETE` query in the above code ?

Comment: That's because I can't figure out how to run the query with the above code.. I know how you perform a `DELETE FROM table WHERE id = something` but not this one..

Comment: We'll need to see the HTML/JavaScript which handles the deletion operation. From your description it sounds like you have an href (AJAX request?) which should handle deletion of the record.

Comment: I've edited my question - see above and have a look at the java script :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inform the PHP script that you wish to delete the record. One solution would be to use a hidden input which is set when you call removeRow, e.g.

```
function removeRow(el) {
    // get the table row
    var row = $(el).parents('tr:first');

    // disable the input fields for the row
    $('input', row).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    // rename update_id to delete_id and re-enable the field
    $('input[name="update_id[]"]', row).attr('name', 'delete_id[]').removeAttr('disabled');

    // hide the row
    row.hide();
}
```

This method no longer removes the table row from the DOM. However, it will disable the input fields contained in the row and adds a hidden input with the name `beskrivelse_delete`.

When the form is submitted, your PHP will now have a way to know which records need to be deleted.

```
foreach ($_POST['delete_id'] as $deleteId) {
    $deleteId = (int)$deleteId;
    $db->query("DELETE FROM faktura_materialer WHERE id = $deleteId");
}
```

---

Update: I've created a [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/y5a-sd5) which has some improvements that you may wish to learn about. These points include:

- Supporting deletion where JavaScript is not enabled
- Using [prepared statements](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) (preferred to `add_slashes`)
- Escaping output by using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)
- Explicitly defining input ids to avoid *guessing* based on an incremental counter

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it well enough, but I want it to run with my javascript - see my edited question above :) but thanks anyway for you answer

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly. Note that I've hardcoded an id of 20, you'll need to concatenate the correct id in place.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried your code, but it doesn't work properly, sadly.. :(

Comment: Oh my bad! It deletes perfectly, but I can't figure out how to do it without hardcoding an id of 20 or 40

Comment: Do you know how I can access the id's of the while loop inside of my javascript code?

Comment: How do you populate the form fields with data? You should be able to use the same technique that has allowed you to create the update logic.

Comment: Yes, but what should I put in the value field in the `beskrivelse_delete` hidden input field?

Comment: I've updated my question again (second edit) with the HTML and PHP on updating my current information

Comment: @dinkode.dk thanks - I've modified removeRow so that it renames update_id[] to delete_id[].

Comment: Thanks - but how do I pass the id of the material into the function removeRow? Like before you hardcoded the value of 20 which removed to id that equals to 20. What should I do now?

Comment: In the updated example this is not necessary. The previously existing field `update_id` already has the correct value. We rename `update_id` to `delete_id` and loop over `$_POST['delete_id']`.

Comment: Oh yes I see. My fault, sorry. I forgot to rename `foreach ($_POST['beskrivelse_delete'] as $deleteId)` to `foreach ($_POST['delete_id'] as $deleteId)`. Thank you @Andrew Mackrodt