# PHP Javascript keep value after submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I keep the value or data in the POST input textfield after submit? For example, if I want to show the user an error, but keeps his written text inside the input textfield? This is my javascript:

```
function myFunction()
{
var table = document.getElementById("produkter_rows");
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
cell1.innerHTML = '<td><input style="width:450px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="beskrivelse_ny[]" value=""></td>';
cell2.innerHTML = '<td><input style="width:60px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="enhed_ny[]" value=""></td>';
cell3.innerHTML = '<td><input style="width:30px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="stk_ny[]" value=""></td>';
cell4.innerHTML = '<td><input style="width:205px;" class="text-input" type="text" name="vejl_eks_moms_ny[]" value=""></td>';
cell5.innerHTML = '<td><a href="#" onclick="removeRow(this)" id="addNew" title="Slet produkt"><img src="images/icons/slet.gif" width="16" alt="Slet" /></a></td>';
}
```

Comment: Might be beneficial to use a few session variables maybe?

Comment: What's happening on submit? Ajax-request - then no form values will be changed. Page refresh - use php sessions.

Comment: You've got an example maybe? I'm barely new to this :)

Comment: AJAXify the form, that way the form stays populated anyway - it's great! :D

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol how can I do that and still keep the same function :)?

Comment: I wouldn't keep your code if I were you. You are putting `<td>...</td>` *inside* something that's already a `<td>`...

Comment: But if I want to keep my code, how should I then do it?

Comment: @dinkode.dk have a look at the phpfiddle in my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/21801571/650329 - I don't have time to explain it all sadly but you may be able to get ideas by reading the code.

Comment: Sure, I used your code, but I don't know how to keep the value of the fields after I submit. If an error has been outputted and the query hasn't been run, then all the values the user has written is gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be handled in PHP instead of JavaScript. Values are output from the database in your question [PHP MySQL Delete function in while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21801512/650329). Now detect if the user has submitted a value for the same field and output that instead.

If the names of your database columns and user submitted fields map exactly you could do something like this:

```
$data = isset($_POST['data']) ? (array)$_POST['data'] : array();

while($mat = $materialer_query->fetch_object()) {
    // true when the user has submitted data for the current object
    if (array_key_exists($mat->id, $data)) {
        foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
            if (property_exists($mat, $k)) {
                // replace the database value with that submitted by the user
                $mat->$k = $v;
            }
        }
    }

    // ... the rest of your code to output the table row
}
```